# DateTime hex format

Tags: datetime, hex

I have the following know pair of hex values and dates:

```
7D 92 D2 5C = 26/03/2009 - 09:28
7D 92 DA CC = 27/03/2009 - 11:12
7D 92 E3 56 = 28/03/2009 - 13:22
7D 92 EC 4F = 29/03/2009 - 17:15
7D 92 F3 16 = 30/03/2009 - 12:22
7D 92 FB 1A = 31/03/2009 - 12:26
7D 93 0B 01 = 01/04/2009 - 12:01
7D 93 12 88 = 02/04/2009 - 10:08
7D 93 1A 30 = 03/04/2009 - 08:48
7D 93 22 DD = 04/04/2009 - 11:29
7D 93 2A D5 = 05/04/2009 - 11:21
```

I cant figure out how to convert from the one to the other....

Anyone recognise the hex format?

Al

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a simple bitfield, even though that's a pretty weird time format :)

```
1111101100100101101001001011100
                         011100 - 28 minutes
                    01001       - 09 hours
               11010            - 26 days
           0010                 - month 3 (zero-based, hence 2)
11111011001                     - 2009 years
```

would be my guess.

Comment: beat me to it. :-) I have seen this format before, but only in another stackoverflow question!

Comment: Yikes ... Initially I tought Unixtime, since none of the common Windows time structures fit into 32 bits, but this is ... strange. Especially that the month is seemingly zero-based but days are not.

Comment: Wow. Thank you Johannes. I really apreciate the answer. And so fast too. Brilliant!

Comment: I looked at dates about 1 day apart, that gave the first clue.

Comment: Well, bitfields were actually my second guess and I sat down with calc and notepad (very handy tools :)) and looked each component up in the bit representation, with just a brief pause with the month :)

Comment: You're leaving out the first bit in your example, which may give someone the false impression that this format won't work past year 2048.

Comment: There is a quite popular format that won't work past 2038 ... I guess it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

12 bit year, 4 bit month (0-based), 5 bit day, 5 bit hour, 6 bit minute.

Nice puzzle :-)

Answer (score 1):

i realize that this is an old topic, but i found it useful and thought i would add to it my 2 cents.

```
u8 getMinutes(u32 in)
{
    return in & 0x3f;
}

u8 getHours(u32 in)
{
    return (in>>6) & 0x1f;
}

u8 getDays(u32 in)
{
    return (in>>11) & 0x1f;
}

u8 getMonths(u32 in)
{
    return ((in>>16)& 0xf)+1;
}

u16 getYears(u32 in)
{
    return (in>>20) & 0x7ff;
}

void printDate(u32 in)
{
    printf("%d/%d/%d - %d:%d", getDays(in), getMonths(in), getYears(in), getHours(in), getMinutes(in));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    u32 t = 0x7D92D25C;
    printDate(t);
    return 0;
}
```