# How to decode this type of string like 51167154:09, 511671AF:08, 511671B1:08

Tags: java, date

I want to decode the above strings and get the date and time they represent, but I don't have any information about their format. I searched but did not find any information of its format.

Is anyone aware of these type of date/time string?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @NiksTyagi Need the string format for decoding

Comment: @NiksTyagi Very funny. The OP says he doesn't know the format. You're adding insult to injury, not very helpful.

Comment: @spt Can you tell us more about these strings? Where do they come from? Do you know at least on date/time that corresponds to one of the strings?

Comment: I m not insulting anyone,just say u need algo and key without it no one cant decode it. @spt if u hurt thn sry dear

Comment: Why the downvote and 'close' vote? The person is asking if anybody recognizes this date-time string format. Seems like a legitimate and interesting question to me.

Comment: Similar question, hex number as seconds-since-epoch but no mention of colon and two digits: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20673724/642706 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20373032/642706

Comment: And [here's a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/719129/642706) where the hex string represented a crazy bit-oriented representation of decimal digits of day-month-year

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if your convert `511671af` to decimal you will get 1360425391 which is seconds, so multiple by 1000 and use

```
 new Date (1360425391000) -> Sun Feb 10 2013 00:56:31
```

Comment: Yeah, no idea what the `:08` and such may be, but it was fairly obvious that the first bit was hex.

Comment: Taking a wild guess… If that is a time zone perhaps it is refers to [military time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_military_time_zones) (click to see chart of zones) which are UTC plus/minus each of 12 whole hours. The US military and others label them with 25 letters of the alphabet (omitting `J`): `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, …. Perhaps :08 is the eighth letter in that series, which would be `H` which is UTC+08:00. So `:15` would be zone `P` for UTC-03:00.