# Recognize the Hex format to Date Time

Tags: datetime, timestamp, hex

The following know pair of hex values and dates:

00 00 00 00 => Jan 01, 1970 07:00 (1)

01 00 00 00 => Jan 01, 1970 07:01 ( > 1 minute than (1)                  => 01 00 00 00)

02 00 00 00 => Jan 01, 1970 07:02 ( > 2 minute than (1)                  => 02 00 00 00)

0F 00 00 00 => Jan 01, 1970 07:16 ( > 16 minute than (1)                   => 10 00 00 00)

FF 00 00 00 => Jan 01, 1970 11:39 ( > 279 minute than (1)                => 17 01 00 00)

FF 01 00 00 => Jan 01, 1970 16:18 ( > 558 minute than (1)                => 2E 02 00 00)

FF 0F 00 00 => Jan 04, 1970 09:33 ( > 4473 minute than (1)             => 79 11 00 00)

FF FF 00 00 => Feb 20, 1970 00:02 ( > 71582 minute than (1)          => 9E 17 01 00)

FF FF 01 00 => Apr 10, 1970 17:05 ( > 143165 minute than (1)           => 3D 2F 02 00)

FF FF 0F 00 => Mar 06, 1972 15:44 ( > 1145324 minute than (1)       => EC 79 11 00)

FF FF 1F 00 => May 11, 1974 00:28 ( > 2290622 minute than (1)      => BE F3 22 00)

FF FF 1F 01 => Mar 13, 2009 20:22 ( > 20615842 minute than (1)    => A2 92 3A 01)

FF FF 5F 01 => Nov 28, 2017 07:20 ( > 25197140 minute than (1)     => 54 7A 80 01)

I guess the result bigger than 10%, but It is not true:

X - 0.1 X = 1; => X = 1  01 00 00 00

I tried convert to timestamp too, using unixtimestamp[dot]50x[dot]eu, but not the correct answer.
By searching the same question, I found [Date to Hex format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/719129/datetime-hex-format) question, but maybe not the same.

So, the question is: **How to convert from the one to the other**.

I can't find out the hex format.
Please help me if you recognize it.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you're looking at (1) a little-endian binary format, and (2) the values are not standard Unix timestamps, and (3) you appear to be in a time zone 7 hours east of Greenwich.  Standard Unix timestamps count seconds since The Epoch (1970-01-01 00:00:00 +00:00).  Your increment of '1' changes the value by 60 seconds, not 1 second.  That makes it non-standard.  As such, there won't be a standard way to do the conversion.

Comment: It also isn't clear to me how the 0F 00 00 00 is greater than 16 minutes after the epoch; 0F is normally 15.  And 0x015FFFFF is decimal 23068671, not 25197140 as in the question.  It is dreadfully unclear to me how these values are supposed to be interpreted.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for your replies. Sorry because my question is not clearly, I want to explain this sentence "how the 0F 00 00 00 is greater than 16 minutes after the epoch", I mean "Jan 01, 1970 07:16 is greater than 16 minutes after Jan 01, 1970 07:00" and "Nov 28, 2017 07:20 is greater than 25197140 minutes after Jan 01, 1970 07:00", I wrote that aim to the other guys don't have to convert to minute by themselves. Inside the parentheses "(...)" is the part I added, you can ignore this section. Anyway, thank you.